# Pyqt - What signal does my standard "Apply" button emit and how do I write the slot for it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, signals-slots, qdialog

I'm just learning pyqt and I'm trying to understand Standard buttons. I'm just learning, so let me know if I did something grossly wrong.

I've created a simple UI with some standard buttons in QT Designer.

I noted that the accepted() and rejected() signals are being connected to the accept and reject slots, so I wrote them. The Ok button and cancel button work as expected, but the Apply button simply doesn't react. How do I connect the apply button to a slot?

sample.py - Here's my sample app code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

import designer

class SampleApp(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = designer.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def reject(w):
        print("reject", w)
        w.close()

    def accept(w):
        print("accept", w)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = SampleApp()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

designer.py - Here's the auto-generated QT Designer code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'designer.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(554, 399)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 340, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Close|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(False)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to connect the `clicked` signal from the *Apply* button manually in your widget.

```
class SampleApp(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = designer.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        btn = self.ui.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.accept)
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to write slots for `accept()` and `reject()`, because the `QDialog` class already has them.

When you create a new form and choose "Dialog with Buttons", it will add a button-box with Ok and Cancel buttons, and the `accepted()/rejected()` signals will be automatically connected to the dialog's existing `accept()` and `reject()` slots.

But note that there is no one-to-one relationship between the buttons and signals. Instead, there is a set of [button roles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#ButtonRole-enum), and each [standard button](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#StandardButton-enum) is assigned one of those roles. All buttons with the `AcceptRole` will emit the `accepted()` signal, those with the `RejectRole` will emit the `rejected()` signal, whilst those with the `HelpRole` will emit the `helpRequested()` signal. But the other roles (such as the `ApplyRole`), do not emit any specific signals other than `clicked()`.

To handle these other buttons you can either connect to each one directly:

```
button = self.ui.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
button.clicked.connect(self.handleApply)
```

or handle them all in a single slot like this:

```
class SampleApp(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = designer.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClick)

    def handleButtonClick(self, button):
        role = self.buttonBox.buttonRole(button)
        if role == QDialogButtonBox.ApplyRole:
            print('Apply Clicked')
        elif role == QDialogButtonBox.ResetRole:
            print('Reset Clicked')        
        # and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the button from the `QDialogButtonBox` and connect `clicked` signal to the desired slot. Also I suggest you to use the [new-style signal and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) support which is way more intuitive:

Here below you define the slots to be triggered. You should decorate them using the @pyqtSlot() decorator. It would work also without the decorator (more info in the documentation page).

```
import sys
import designer

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class SampleApp(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = designer.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def reject(self):
        print("reject")
        self.close()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def accept(self):
        print("accept")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def apply(self):
        print("apply")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = SampleApp()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here below instead you connect the `clicked` action of the buttons to the slots you defined up here. Note that for `Close` and `Ok` that was not really necessary because when using StandardButtons PyQt automatically connect them to the default actions if not specified by the programmer. Although I connected them manually so you get the idea of what's going on.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'designer.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(554, 399)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 340, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Close|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(False)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Close).clicked.connect(Dialog.reject)
        self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply).clicked.connect(Dialog.apply)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be reading up to understand the rest of your answer, but one question: 

My understanding is that I should not change the "PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4" generated code as it will change as I change my UI. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, well, you can do the same without changing the generated code. From within your `SampleApp` class, you can get the reference to the `QPushButton` "Apply" in the same way I did inside `Ui_Dialog`, and attach the `clicked` signal to the slot.